# PowerShell Compare Outputs

Tags: powershell, compare

I've got a text file where I'am storing some backup file names with their hash tables. I've got another text file where I'am storing only hash tables. I add the second text file under the first documents. I want to compare these hash tables if they are the same, I want to add near the hash table -2, else I want to add near the hash table -1.

> - "SHA256","89EC548C14582B2BDC7739BC0FA007","C:\WINDOWS\system32@Ap.png"
> - "SHA256","0B99B2576F1FA0689FF6E03462076C","C:\WINDOWS\system32@AudioTot"
> - "SHA256","F3B178AD338023AA3CBCB071CC0063","C:\WINDOWS\system32@biage.png"
> - "SHA256","383D8CBFCD078B3D661655A816676F","C:\WINDOWS\system32@edage.mui"
> - "89EC548C14582B2BDC7739BC0FA007" -2
> - "0B99B2576F1FA0689FF6E03462076C" -2
> - "0A57D7F60CDD9DB6F6F461BBC464FD" -1
> - "F3B178AD338023AA3CBCB071CC0063" -2
> - "7BCA060610F1A753A881593F967G47" -1
> - "383D8CBFCD078B3D661655A816676F" -2

I am using add the hashes under the txt file from another file but could not compare :

```
$From = Get-Content -Path .\CopyFromFile.txt

Add-Content -Path .\CopyToFile.txt -Value $From

Get-Content -Path .\CopyToFile.txt
```

Comment: Is the order relevant ? the hashes with -1 belongs to files that were  not in from directory ?

Comment: No it is not relevant. I have more than 65k line like that. I just wanted to give example. In other txt file also same, there is an directories same format. I want to specify same hash tables but with "SHA256" concept I couldn't specify (my guess was giving something like -2 then delete -1's.)

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. How many files do you have and what is their content? Please create sample input files and copy/paste their content into your question. Make clear what content belongs to which file. Also provide a sample of the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon me, but I don't think it is a clever approach to create a text file with different formats inside.

Why not using a more `PowerShell` like way with `Import-Csv` and `Compare-Object` creating a new object which can also be saved as a csv file.

Presuming the above data is stored in files `hashes.csv` and the pure hashes in `hashes.txt`

This small script (line)

```
Compare-Object -ref (Import-Csv .\hashes.csv -Header Algorythm,Hash,File) `
               -dif (Import-csv .\hashes.txt -Header Hash) -Property Hash -PassThru -IncludeEqual
```

yields this output:

```
Algorythm Hash                           File                          SideIndicator
--------- ----                           ----                          -------------
SHA256    89EC548C14582B2BDC7739BC0FA007 C:\WINDOWS\system32@Ap.png    ==
SHA256    0B99B2576F1FA0689FF6E03462076C C:\WINDOWS\system32@AudioTot  ==
SHA256    F3B178AD338023AA3CBCB071CC0063 C:\WINDOWS\system32@biage.png ==
SHA256    383D8CBFCD078B3D661655A816676F C:\WINDOWS\system32@edage.mui ==
          0A57D7F60CDD9DB6F6F461BBC464FD                               =>
          7BCA060610F1A753A881593F967G47                               =>
```

which could be tweaked to replace the `SideIndicator` with your values `-2`,`-1`

Comment: yes I tried this approach before but for my scenario it wasn't enough, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the following code helps solve your problem.
The code was wrapped in a script block to create a new scope and [preserve](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-custom-scopes) the values of the `$ErrorActionPreference` and `$OFS` [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6).
The [`ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8) method was used to read the contents of the `CopyToFile.txt` file.

```
& {
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  $OFS = ','
  try {
    $To = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('.\CopyToFile.txt')
    $From = & {
      # Add a line if the file .\CopyToFile.txt did not end with a newline.
      if ( -not $To.EndsWith([System.Environment]::NewLine) ) { '' }
      Get-Content -Path .\CopyFromFile.txt |
        ForEach-Object { "$($_, @(-1, -2)[[int]$To.Contains($_)])" }
    }
    Add-Content -Path .\CopyToFile.txt -Value $From
    Get-Content -Path .\CopyToFile.txt
  } catch {
    $_ | Out-String | Write-Warning
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"SHA256","89EC548C14582B2BDC7739BC0FA007","C:\WINDOWS\system32@Ap.png"
"SHA256","0B99B2576F1FA0689FF6E03462076C","C:\WINDOWS\system32@AudioTot"
"SHA256","F3B178AD338023AA3CBCB071CC0063","C:\WINDOWS\system32@biage.png"
"SHA256","383D8CBFCD078B3D661655A816676F","C:\WINDOWS\system32@edage.mui"
"89EC548C14582B2BDC7739BC0FA007",-2
"0B99B2576F1FA0689FF6E03462076C",-2
"0A57D7F60CDD9DB6F6F461BBC464FD",-1
"F3B178AD338023AA3CBCB071CC0063",-2
"7BCA060610F1A753A881593F967G47",-1
"383D8CBFCD078B3D661655A816676F",-2
```